# SQL Server AlwaysOn connection and and MultiSubnetFailover=True C# code example

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am going through the following article and I understand that I should use MultiSubnetFailover=True option in SqlClient in order to be able to have faster failover for all Availability Groups and or Failover Cluster Instance:

SqlClient Support for High Availability, Disaster Recovery (
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205662(v=vs.110).aspx)

My understanding is that I need to implement a special re-try login in my C# code in conjunction with MultiSubnetFailover in the connection string. Am I correct?
 Do we have a code sample how to implement the re-try logic?

Thank you,

Comment: Hey, it has been a couple of years for this post. Though, if you remember how did you proceed that time, it would be great if you could answer it here.